# Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ be convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ absolutely convergent. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ be convergent and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$ absolutely convergent. Is it true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_ny_n$ converges?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i y_i$ is absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010093/show-sum-i-1-infty-x-i-y-i-is-absolutely-convergent). Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795166/42969.

Comment: You are thinking too complicated. It suffices that $(x_n)$ is a *bounded* sequence.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, that is much simpler.